# Como transformar uma lista [['a'], ['b']] em uma string: ab

Tags: python, lista

```
quantidade = int(input())
lista = []
lista2 = []
lista3 = []
palavra =()
i = 0
while quantidade != len(lista):
    a = input()
    lista.append(a)
for x in lista:
    b = x.split()
    lista2.append(b)
for x in lista2:
    x[0] = int(x[0])
del(lista[0:quantidade - 1])
lista2.sort()
for x in lista2:
    del(x[0])
    lista3.append(x)
print(lista3)
```

link do problema: https://www.thehuxley.com/problem/2197/code-editor/?quizId=3169

Comment: É uma pergunta ? Se sim qual é a pergunta ? O código não funciona ? Não faz o esperado ? Dá erro ?

Comment: Lista `[['a'], ['b']]` ou matriz `[['a'], ['b']]`?

Answer (score 2):

(Respondendo o título, porque o resto não entendi nada, por favor edite e melhore a pergunta)

Partindo de uma lista, podemos concatenar seus valores de varias maneiras como:

```
lista = ['o','l','a']

string = ''.join(lista)
string = ''.join([x for x in lista])
string = ''.join(map(lambda x: x, lista))

def concatena(lista):
    string = ''
    for x in lista:
        string += x
    return string    
string = concatena(lista)

>>> print(string)
ola
```

E podemos até modificar se necessário:

```
string = ''.join([x.upper() for x in lista]) #ou .lower()
```

Complicando um pouco, mas não muito, podemos brincar com matrizes. Agora é só pegar as listas da matriz e aplicar um método acima.

```
matriz = [['o'],['l'],['a']]

#string = ''.join(map(lambda lista: Algum_metodo_acima, matriz))
#string = ''.join([Algum_metodo_acima for lista in matriz])

string = ''.join(map(lambda lista: ''.join(lista), matriz))
string = ''.join([''.join(lista) for lista in matriz])

def concatena_matriz(matriz):
    string = ''
    for lista in matriz:
        for x in lista:
            string += x
    return string

string = concatena_matriz(matriz)

>>> print(string)
ola
```

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi sua pergunta, você quer extrair os dados de uma lista e colocar em string, se for isso, existem várias de fazer, uma delas é usando ListComps.

```
alfabeto = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]

''.join([letras for lista in alfabeto 
                for letras in lista])
```

> Saída: 'abc'